# How to filter product collection in such way where I can use having and addfiledtofilter with AND condition?

Tags: magento2, product-attribute, product-collection

I am having product collection where I am getting one custom product attribute called "keep_disabled" and another column which was added on runtime which is sum of quantities 'sum_qty'.
I just want to get the product collection where keep disable is true and sum of quantity is greater than 0.
I can filter out the quantity by :

```
$collection->getSelect()->having('sum_qty > 0');
```

but I also want to add filter :

```
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('keep_disabled', array(array('neq' => 1) , array('eq' => 0),array('null' => true)));
```

I only want those products where (if keep disable is false, don't check the quantity) and (if keep disable is true, get only those products where quantity is greater than 0);
so basically don't want to show those products where keep disable is true and quantity is 0.

Comment: Try this one : $collection->addAttributeToFilter('keep_disabled',['eq' => 1]);$collection->getSelect()->having('sum_qty > 0');

Comment: Hello @RohanHapani, from the first filter, it will filter out keep_disabled = 0, but as per my question, I want to keep keep disable = 0 as well.

Comment: You mean you want keep_disabled 0 & 1 both records?

Comment: yes, if (keep_disable = false => get all records) + (keep_disable = true, get records where sum_qty is greater than 0).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After struggling 2 days with MySql and Magento queries, I finally found the solution.
As of my findings, I found out that this not possible with direct Magento query or direct MySql query but it can be possible by creating MySql VIEW table.
I passed my mysql query with dynamic column and used that view as a normal table, then only I was able to filter with where condition as like an existing column.
Hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

Hello You can Used OR Operation in collection to achieve this condition

yes, if (keep_disable = false => get all records) + (keep_disable = true, get records where sum_qty is greater than 0)

Check the below link for used of OR Operation in magento Collection

https://meetanshi.com/blog/apply-or-conditions-to-collection-in-magento-2/

Comment: Thanks Harishit, but issue was that the the quantity column was a temp column which was created run time, so we cannot use WHERE condition on it, the only way to use that column in filtering is to create a view for that and then only we can filter it as a regular column.